# Timezone issue when filtering XTS using .indexhour

Tags: r, timezone, xts

The following R code returns an unexpected output:

```
times = c("2014-12-01 15:59:00", "2014-12-01 16:00:00", "2014-12-01 16:01:00")
values = c(64.23, 64.43, 64.31)
tim <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-01 15:59:00", "2014-12-01 16:00:00", "2014-12-01 16:01:00"), tz="GMT")
myts <- xts(values, tim, tzone="GMT")
print(myts[.indexhour(myts)==16])
```

I get:

```
                     [,1]
2014-12-01 15:59:00 64.23
```

While I would expect:

```
                     [,1]
2014-12-01 16:00:00 64.43
2014-12-01 16:01:00 64.31
```

I think .indexhour is somehow referring to my local timezone, while I obviously expect it to use the XTS object timezone.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [bug #5891](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5891&group_id=118&atid=516) and has been patched on R-Forge as of [revision 844](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=xts&revision=844).