# xts subset - daylight savings time

Tags: r, timezone, subset, xts

I am trying to index specific minutes of a 1-min frequency dataset. (I have always used 'T../T..' because .indexmin had(/has?) some [problems with timezones.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943770/timezone-issue-when-filtering-xts-using-indexhour))

The following two xts objects have the same length (nrow), no duplicates and the subset below should return zero (no obs at 2am). One works, the other doesn't (returns all obs). I think this is related to DST transition (although both have EDT as index). `Sys.timezone()` is also set to `EST5EDT`. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
xcheck1 <- readRDS(gzcon(url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8yg9q854umipjna/xts_problem_1.rds"))) 
xcheck2 <- readRDS(gzcon(url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qm83b0ayz03appg/xts_problem_2.rds")))
xcheck1['T02:00/T02:00:10']
xcheck2['T02:00/T02:00:10']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/3) and has been fixed in the latest CRAN release (0.10-0). It now returns what you expect (nothing), in both cases.

```
library(xts)
Sys.setenv(TZ = "EST5EDT")
urls <- paste0("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/",
               c("8yg9q854umipjna", "qm83b0ayz03appg"),
               "/xts_problem_", 1:2, ".rds")
xcheck1 <- readRDS(gzcon(url(urls[1])))
xcheck2 <- readRDS(gzcon(url(urls[2])))
xcheck1['T02:00/T02:00:10']
#      AUDUSD.ask.Close
xcheck2['T02:00/T02:00:10']
#      AUDUSD.ask.Close
packageVersion("xts")
# [1] '0.10.0'
```